# Table of Contents in Separate File

Tags: table-of-contents, lists, pdf, report

I am using `\documentclass[oneside, 12pt, a4paper]{report}`. Now I want to use `\tableofcontents,` `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` but in a separate file, not with the main document. Shortly, I want multiple files where 1 pdf consist of lists and others are main chapters. Is it possible, Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible but I don't see the point. I think you are asking for a PDF file of the main body and a PDF file of the ToC, etc. Or are you asking for `.tex` files of the main body and the ToC etc.?

The following is not automatic and needs a lot of work on your part.

I'm starting with a reasonably bland `report` document that will produce a PDF which includes the ToC etc and the main body.

```
% loftoc2.tex  SE 632927

\documentclass{report}

%\nofiles    % don't up date lists
\begin{document}
%\input{cftlists} % no lists printed
\input{cftlists}

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Together with

```
% cftlists.tex
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
```

Which when processed will typeset a `loftoc2.pdf` document that includes the Lists and the main body, which you don't seem to want.

Then a revision of the original, which has to be processed after the original

```
% loftoc2.tex  SE 632927

\documentclass{report}

\nofiles    % don't update lists
\begin{document}
%\input{cftlists} % no lists printed
\input{cftlists}

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Which will produce `loftoc2.pdf` with only the body typeset. Save this file.

And follow this by

```
% loftoc2.tex  SE 632927

\documentclass{report}

\nofiles    % don't update lists
\begin{document}
%\input{cftlists} % no lists printed
\input{cftlists}

\end{document}

\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which will result in another `loftoc2.pdf` containing  only the lists.

It is up to you to keep trace, and possibly change the name of the generated PDF files.

Perhaps some advance apologies in that I might have got mixed up in the order to do things.